# Linking tables in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, multiple-tables

I cant figure out how to link fields between 2 content-types in Drupal 7. For example...

I'm building an online shop using Drupal 7. There are several product categories and each category has its own page that displays all the products in that category plus a category description.

I store this data in two tables (content types). See below.

```
categories content-type:
category_name, description
----------------------------------------------
paintings, "A selection of paintings that we supply. Prices include ...."
ceramics, ....
jewellery, ....
```

.

```
products content-type:
name, category_name, price, ...
---------------------------------------------------
mona-lisa, paintings, £10,
necklace1, jewellery, £20,
necklace2, jewellery, £30,
```

.

The common field is 'category_name'. In the first table I define all the values for category_name and in the second table, each time I add a new product, I want to be able to pick one category to assign to the product. Does anyone know how to do this?

You can reuse fields between content types but you cant change the widget type (the 'categories' content-type needs free-text entry and the 'products' content-type needs a selector.

In Drupal 6 there seemed to be a 'node reference' field type which might be what I'm looking for but I cant figure out how to get this in Drupal7.

Comment: Why not use the taxonomy module for your categories?

Comment: @mirzu Thanks. That worked (Had difficulty getting my head around taxonomys - didnt realise you could add custom fields)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This module is still in progress but you can use [references](http://drupal.org/project/references) for that.

Comment: thanks. I'm beginning to think I should start out with Drupal 6 as D7 seems to have lots of critical stuff still in development.

Comment: If everything that you need is in Drupal 6 and that your project is supposed to be ready soon (less than 6 months) yes, it's probably a good idea. ;)